# Unable to connect to Windows 8 created network

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

When hosting a WPA2 infrastructure network on my Windows 8 PC (though this happened on XP for me too, but I do not have that computer anymore), I am only able to connect the first device (iPhone) attempted. When trying to connect a different device or the same one after disconnecting from the network, it will not assign any IP or fill any other forms (router, DNS, so on...) through DHCP and displays `unable to join network`.

Originally, I was using the program [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/), but this was not the problem because when trying to do the same thing through the [command line](http://www.howtogeek.com/112050/how-to-turn-your-windows-8-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/), I got the same results.

I was hoping not to have to assign static IP addresses to each device as a alternative, but (any?) alternative suggested I'll attempt.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Sickest It doesn't have anything to do with a router (unless your talking about the internet connection that I am trying to share). What made you think this?

Comment: @Sickest Did you take a look at one of my links in the question? I'm hosting the network FROM my windows 8 laptop's WiFi card. It's pretty simple: I am retransmitting the internet FROM a router. The DHCP problem is with the local network (LAN) that I'm transmitting. After connecting the first device, no other devices will retrieve IPs ON MY TRANSMITTED NETWORK! Look at the question harder rather than pointing the finger as if I don't know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Sorry I deleted all my recent comments since I clearly have no idea what i'm talking about after 15 years of networking experince and can't for the life of me figure out why anyone would setup a network like you have. which is why no one has responded to your bounty. Good luck.

Comment: Do your other/later clients actually connect to the network? Because it sounds to me like they don't. Which would be a totally different matter from DHCP. Have you tried any other devices than your iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide enough information about your current setup, so I have to go on a few assumptions, namely a standard setup with a LAN and WLAN adapter, a reasonably up-to-date- MS Windows 8 PC and no 3rd party firewalls, etc. I would ask, but I'm not allowed to post comments yet ;)

First off, you should run `netsh wlan show driver` to see if your driver supports SoftAPs. If not, hunt for a more recent driver.

Second, you need to enable ICS on the hardware NIC connected to your (W)LAN and you need to select the "virtual wifi adapter" provided by MS for the "home networking connection". I don't know why the screenshot in the how-to is missing this option.

Third, if you are missing the virtual wifi NIC, check if it is disabled. If so, enable it. If the virtual wifi adapter is missing completely you need to remove and reinstall your wifi NIC drivers. MS Windows should then automatically also install the virtual wifi NIC.

Here is what MS has to say about this issue: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd815243%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: are you sure that it would work in the way it was descripted without softap support?

Comment: On the contrary. I'm sure it will not work without SoftAP support. I think the option is named "Hosted Network Support" in English output variants of `netsh wlan show driver`.

Comment: @ahaw probably referred to the fact that a connection is successfully established, if only once. Even getting a network to show would be impossible without an AP-Mode compatible driver.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Virtual WiFi Hotspot?

> Virtual Wifi Hotspot turns any Windows 7 and Windows 8 computer into a Wifi Hotspot using Wireless hosted network technology.
>
> Virtual Wifi Hotspot is a free, open source software based router for PCs running Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2012. Using Virtual Wifi Hotspot, users can wirelessly share any internet connection (Wifi, LAN, Cable Modem, Dial-up, Cellular, etc.) with any Wifi device (Laptop, Smart Phone, iPod Touch, iPhone, Android Phone, Zune, Netbook, wireless printer, etc.) These devices connect to Virtual Wifi Hotspot just like any other access point, and the connection is completely secured using WPA2 (the most secure wireless encryption.)

Comment: 404 not found on your link.